# SIP: Writing sound from buffer and reading sound to buffer when making a call

Tags: sip

There are a lot of SIP clients, including command line like Baresip, but is there a way to write into SIP media stream and read from it programmatically, without using a sound card? Like redirecting STDIN/STDOUT there?

I want make an app that plays sound file from stdin to the SIP call stream. And writes what the other party is saying to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? You can maybe do this by using freeswitch or asterisk

Comment: I want make an app that plays sound file from stdin to the SIP call stream. And writes what the other party is saying to stdout.

Comment: then you need to start by reading the SIP specifications and read about how media is setup during a SIP session. There will be two data channels for audio.

The SIP protocol is just a signaling protocol and does not have any audio. If you are going to write your own sip client, you have a loot of work in front of you, as there will be many issues, specially with NAT support, if you need that. You will also have encode/decode the audio streams from ulaw,alaw, g729, gsm etc.

if this is an app that should run a computer, use freeswitch/asterisk. you can do it them. They are opensource

Comment: I definetely don't want to write full SIP stack :) How do I do that using freeswitch/asterisk? I've read the manuals, but there is nothing about what I need.

Comment: They have very good documentation, start there. My favourite is freeswitch.